# How do I write a Python program to print the pattern?

Tags: python

How do I write a Python program to print the pattern?
543210
432105
321054
210543
054321
543210

Comment: `print('543210 432105 321054 210543 054321 543210')`?

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Comment: The tags `pattern-matching` and `design-patterns` have **nothing to do with** making patterns with terminal text output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it by something like this:

```
a = "543210"
print(a)

for i in range(6):

    a = a + (a[0])

    a = a[1:]

    print(a)
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering zero-effort questions; we do not want to encourage them.